# Graphql + axios - filtering and sorting

Tags: graphql, axios

How can I filter and sort data? Regarding about sorting, should I use gatsby.js? Is there other way?

```
const RootQuery = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: "Query",
  description: "Root Query",
  fields: () => ({
    member: {
      type: MemberType,
      description: "A Single Person",
      args: {
        nick: { type: GraphQLString }
      },
      resolve(parent, args) {
        return axios
          .get("http://25.98.140.121:5000/data")
          .then(members.find(member => member.nick === args.nick))
      }
    },
    members: {
      type: new GraphQLList(MemberType),
      description: "List of All Members",
      resolve(parent, args) {
        return axios
          .get("http://25.98.140.121:5000/data")
          .then(res => res.data)
      }
    },
    school: {
      type: SchoolType,
      description: "A Single School",
      args: {
        name: { type: GraphQLString }
      },
      resolve: (parent, args) => schools.find(school => school.name === args.name)
    },
    schools: {
      type: new GraphQLList(SchoolType),
      description: "List of All Schools",
      resolve(parent, args) {
        return axios
          .get("http://25.98.140.121:5000/data")
          .then(res => res.data)
    }
  })
});
```

Of course above filtering (school, member) doesn't work because I don't know how to connect 'find' and 'return axios'.
 In this way I didn't get filtered data, when I use member(nick: John) or school(name: XYZ). 
Hope you understand what I mean. What should I change? Or maybe you have other solution?

Comment: Please be specific about what code "doesn't work". You have four different functions there. Which one are you having a problem with?

Comment: Sorry, I have already edited my post.

Answer (score 0):

You're not too far off. `axios.get` returns a Promise, which you are correctly returning inside your resolver. You're also correctly using `then` to modify the resolved value of that Promise. The only issue here is that the argument passed to `then` should be a function. So you want to do something like:

```
return axios
  .get("http://25.98.140.121:5000/data")
  .then(res => res.data.find(member => member.nick === args.nick))
```

Whatever function you pass to `then` will be called with the resolved value of the Promise you're calling `then` on. So if `axios.get` returns a Promise that will resolve to an array of member of objects, that's the value that will be passed to your function. Note that we defined the function inline above, but it could be defined separately as well:

```
const getMemberByNick = (res) => res.data.find(member => member.nick === args.nick)

return axios
  .get("http://25.98.140.121:5000/data")
  .then(getMemberByNick)
```

or even

```
const getMemberByNick = (data) => data.find(member => member.nick === args.nick)

return axios
  .get("http://25.98.140.121:5000/data")
  .then(res => getMemberByNick(res.data))
```

Comment: Now I am getting "members.find is not a function".
Thank you!

Comment: Oops. axios returns a [response object](https://github.com/axios/axios#response-schema) so we need to access the `data` property on that